# Can't validate mine, sudo nor root in Debian "Jessie" Gnome anymore?

Tags: linux, debian, gnome, sudo, password-recovery

I'm Debian beginner & GUI guy in a bit of trouble?

Can't login as sudo/gksu/root/su nor as (main/super)user after removed user password via Gnome-user-settings.

---

### History of actions

*(Probably irrelevant though)*

- Installed Debian "Jessie" GNU/Linux with xFce GUI (en-US) as only OS. HardWare is ThinkPad w510.
- Skipped root user password in setup, to get sudo for superuser
  easily.
- Logged in (as always had) with Gnome (3.4.x), not once with xFCE.
  (installed Xfce. Installed xFce only to achieve more control (easier management) over packages this way, to set-up gnome much more by mine likes.
- Added more jessie repros (same ones as in Wheesy stable by default but for
  Jessie as, Jessie only had repros for security updates by default).
- Installed lots of gtk(3) & gnome(3) based soft; (- restarted again after
  this)
- Installed propietary graphics card driver for mine nvidia quadro.  (- restarted
  once again after that one)
- Installed more stuff related to mine work/school/devel.

### The actual problem

- Had a plan to restart again, but wanted to set up auto-login first, instead set user password to none (don't ask why / perhaps caused by being awake for a looooong time), noticed it, and set also to auto-login, but couldn't undo mine previous mistake to create new password for me.
- As mine password is set to none I would have expected that simply return in pass prompt for emty password field would do, but it won't authenticate. I tried Alt+F2 "gksu gedit" as well as: sudo wget "https://www.some-page.eu/file.ext" and "su" in terminals, none has applied (quite logical actually - as I'm sudoer and highest ranked super user, besides only user in computer).

### Current stand

- Everything worked & still works nice after this accident, besides this password prompts part.
- To spoked to log-out nor restart.
- Synaptic package-manager is still open with root rights (only one, that has left open prior to the issue and not closed since, just in case).

---

Goggled for help and read some manuals/faqs/how-tos - mostly lead to sudoers file management, but not found one specifically for mine issue - so still not any smarter.

---

Really hope, that I don't have to redo OS inst all over again, by just one stupid mistake.

---

Thanks for your reply :-)

Comment: So you can still login?  Can you get to a terminal and do `passwd` to set a new password?

Comment: never loged out after this. but while being loged in, no mater where (various graphical & terminal password promts) nor by whom (me, root & me as root/sudo) asked by, password isn't valid. By mine logic, I should enter nothing for mine pass as no user password is set.

Comment: Yep, passwd did the trick :D, also terminal sudo verifies :). alt+f2 'gksu gedit' didn't :(, but I suspect its fixed after logout/reboot ;).

Comment: @Janar, a trivial point but in English "mine" and "my" are different words, and your question would be a little easier to understand for a native speaker if you replaced "mine" almost throughout with "my". (See http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/24722/my-vs-mine-adjectives-vs-possessive for explanation of how they work, also 'you' vs 'yours' etc...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your user's password when booting to `recovery mode' - it will show you root shell after boot.

to change password use `passwd username' and then reboot again to normal mode.